# Prove that : $(ab-1)(ac-1)(bc-1)\equiv 0\pmod{abc}\implies (a,b,c)=(2,3,5)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a<b<c$ are prime numbers

Prove that :

If :

> $$abc \mid (ab-1)(ac-1)(bc-1) \implies (a,b,c)=(2,3,5)$$

Or :

$$(ab-1)(ac-1)(bc-1)\equiv 0\pmod{abc}\implies (a,b,c)=(2,3,5)$$

My try :

After multiplying we get :

$$abc|(abc)^{2}-(abc^{2}+bca^{2}+acb^{2})+(bc+ac+ab)-1$$

Then I know that : $abc$ divides $abc^{2}+bca^{2}+acb^{2}$ and $(abc)^{2}$

But I don't if this step correct or no :

$\implies abc|ab+ac+bc-1$

I this rule correct :

$$x | y+z\implies x\|\_{z} ?? $$

Comment: What does $abc| _{(ab-1)(ac-1)(bc-1)}$ denote??

Comment: @Bernard its  Divisible ? Its clearly

Comment: It is not clear at all, as $(ab-1)(ac-1)(bc-1)$ is in the position of an index –  which is used to denote the restriction of a function to a subset

Answer (score 3):

You have correctly got to the requirement of

$$abc \mid ab+ac+bc-1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

You can't do much with checking the divisibility of $abc$ with the individual terms, as you seem to be trying. Instead, note that $a$, $b$ and $c$ being prime numbers with

$$a \lt b \lt c \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

means $abc$ and $ab + ac + bc - 1$ are positive integers. The condition in \eqref{eq1A} means $ab + ac + bc - 1$ is an integral multiple of $abc$. In particular, it means that

$$ab + ac + bc - 1 \ge abc \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

From \eqref{eq2A}, you have $bc \gt ab$ and $bc \gt ac$. Thus, using this and \eqref{eq3A}, you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
bc + bc + bc - 1 & \gt ab + ac + bc - 1 \\
3bc - 1 & \gt abc \\
3bc - abc & \gt 1 \\
(3-a)bc & \gt 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

If $a \ge 3$, then the LHS would be non-positive, i.e., $\le 0$, which is not possible. Thus, you must have $a = 2$. As such, \eqref{eq3A} now becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2b + 2c + bc - 1 & \ge 2bc \\
2b + 2c - 1 & \ge bc \\
2c - 1 & \ge (b - 2)c
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

If $b \gt 3$, then $b \ge 5$, but then you get from \eqref{eq5A} that $2c - 1 \ge 3c \implies -1 \ge c$, which is not true. Thus, $b = 3$. Now, using $a = 2$ and $b = 3$ in \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
6c & \mid 6 + 2c + 3c - 1 \\
6c & \mid 5 + 5c \\
6c & \mid 5(1 + c)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since $\gcd(c, 1 + c) = 1$, this means $c \mid 5$, so you must have $c = 5$.

This shows the only possible values for $a$, $b$ and $c$ are $2$, $3$ and $5$, but they also work in \eqref{eq1A} since $30 \mid 6 + 10 + 15 - 1 = 30$, and you can add the various other terms in the expansion to get back to the original equation. Also, you can manually confirm these values work since $(ac - 1)(ab - 1)(bc - 1) = 5(3)(3)(2)(7)$, which is divisible by $abc = 30 = 2(3)(5)$.

In conclusion, this shows there is just one solution to the original problem, with this being the one you stated of $(a,b,c) = (2,3,5)$.

Comment: thanks! But why $abc \mid ab+ac+bc-1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$ ?? For example $3$ divide $12=4+8$ but $3$ don't divide $8$ or $4$ can you explain to me ??

Comment: @EllenEllen You're welcome. I'm not sure, but I think I know what you're asking about. If you have $a \mid b + c$, you're right that, in general, it doesn't mean $a \mid b$ or $a \mid c$, as your example shows. However, if you do somehow know that, say, $a \mid b$, then you also know $a \mid c$. This is because $b = ja$, for some integer $j$, and $b + c = ka$, for some integer $k$. Thus, $ja + c = ka \implies c = (k - j)a \implies a \mid c$. This can be extended to cases like $a \mid b + c + d$, where you know $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$, so it must mean $a \mid d$. This is the case with ...

Comment: @EllenEllen (cont.) your original expansion. You have that $abc$ *must* divide the sum since the question is only interested in cases where it does. Since $abc \mid (abc)^2$, and $abc \mid -(abc^{2}+bca^{2}+acb^{2})$ as $-(abc^{2}+bca^{2}+acb^{2}) = -abc(c + a + b)$, then this means that $abc$ has to divide the sum of the remaining terms, i.e., $(bc+ac+ab)-1 = ab + ac + bc - 1$. Thus, I got my equation (1), which I used in my answer to prove the only solution is $(2,3,5)$. Please let me know if this doesn't fully resolve your issues.